# How is the user experience of the new profile page being measured?

Tags: discussion, design, uxexchange

I don't mind the new look and feel of the new user profile page, and there were a lot of discussions about how it should be designed plus the rationale behind design decisions.

I wonder how then, will the success of the redesign be measured, to find out whether the design decisions and rationales were valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there will be any formal measurement to collect data on the new design, but the crew are currently collecting feedback from users at meta. See [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/180230)

Comment: Seems like we could (and should) have a better way to measure and analyse the overall user experience for UXSE, if only because this is probably one of the few places that we can get this implemented without having to twist the arms of business stakeholders :D

Comment: @MichaelLai True! We could do it, but I think they use employees with UX focus on this one... Hidden from us mortal users :-)